# Why does Google Lighthouse not count all the DOM elements for its DOM size calculation

Tags: javascript, dom, lighthouse

I am looking into reducing the size of a website's DOM.
When I run Lighthouse over a page the DOM rightly highlighted as excessive is 1,824 elements.
When I then go into the console and run a small script `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` it returns `HTMLCollection(2212) [HTML, ...]` which is somewhat higher.
I am assuming either

- one of those two results is incorrect - in which case which
- Lighthouse excludes certain elements from its count  - in which case what
- something else.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 2):

Google Lighthouse is counting the DOM elements within the `<body>` only.

`document.getElementsByTagName('*')` returns DOM elements including the `<head>`

Comment: Thanks Dan That did occur to me, so I also ran `$('body *');` which was still over 2,000. So this makes me think perhaps that the Lighthouse total stops counting once the DOM has loaded, anything that might get loaded after that isn't included in the total whereas fiddling in the console might just pick that up. Does this sound feasible?

Comment: Lighthouse does multiple page loads to do the analysis. I was able to reproduce the results on a few different pages on one of my sites. Ones that are fairly static and ones that are dynamic and load things well after the page has loaded. It seems consistent as long as I'm using `querySelectorAll("body *")`. I haven't tried it with jQuery to see if it returns the same.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns the same as the jQuery equivalent - I was being lazy. Looks like my major discrepancy was the difference between mobile and desktop. I hadn't considered the setting in Lighthouse. They still do not quite match but are considerably closer